# How can I create a repeating 'A A B B' pattern with the modulus operator

Tags: javascript, modulus

I'm trying to figure this out elegantly, but I think I've just gotten myself confused. With an array input of arbitrary length and contents (e.g., `[0,1,2,3,4,5,...]`) I'd like the output to be:

```
[
    { slide: 0, style: 'A' },
    { slide: 1, style: 'A' },
    { slide: 2, style: 'B' },
    { slide: 3, style: 'B' },
    { slide: 4, style: 'A' },
    { slide: 5, style: 'A' },
    { slide: 6, style: 'B' },
    { slide: 7, style: 'B' },
    { slide: 8, style: 'A' },
    { slide: 9, style: 'A' },
    { slide: 10, style: 'B' },
    { slide: 11, style: 'B' },
    ...
]
```

So just the `A A B B` pattern repeated.

This is what I've tried, but it seems to break down after a few iterations.

```js
const slides = [...Array(24).keys()];

const getStyleForIndex = (index) => {
    if ((index) % 4 === 0 || (index) % 5 === 0 || index === 1) {
        return 'A';
    }
    return 'B';
};

const newSlides = slides.map((slide, index) => ({ slide: slide, style: getStyleForIndex(index) }));

console.log(newSlides);
```

Any help wrangling the modulus operator here would be much appreciated!

Comment: i would just add a flag or some kind of other tracker. that will make it easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `index % 4` in both cases, not `index % 5`. This returns a sequence of numbers that cycle through `0, 1, 2, 3`.

```
if (index % 4 == 0 || index % 4 == 1) {
    return 'A';
} else {
    return 'B';
}
```

or more simply:

```
return index % 4 < 2 ? 'A' : 'B';
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much @Barmar. I knew there had to be a way to do it. Thanks for clarifying how the modulus works there. 

Answer (score 1):

You could take a different approach by bit shifting and checking for odd numbers.

The shifting takes the number and divide it by two (because of two of the same values in order) and takes the integer value and the next check is for checking the group.

```js
var i = 0;

while (i < 10) {
    console.log(i, i >> 1 & 1 ? 'B' : 'A');
    i++;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```